# Differential LPF cutout frequency simulation

Tags: differential

While designing a thermocouple circuit, I saw that a 1 nF capacitor was placed at the differential signal input as shown in the figure. This was added for both differential signals, so I can see from the simulation that it is a common mode LPF. We can say that it has a cut-off frequency of 15.87775 kHz, approximately 16 kHz.

However, when I analyzed the differential low-pass filter, we can say that it is 793.88741 Hz, approximately 0.8 kHz. However, in this image, the cut-off frequency is stated as 1.3 kHz. What point am I missing?

When I add 1 nF and 1 nF caps to the simulation, the cut-off frequency becomes 756.08325 Hz. How was the 1.3 kHz cut-off frequency reached?

[image]

[image]

Source: [analog devices Analog Dialogue 44-10, October (2010)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/analog-dialogue/volume-44/number-4/articles/measuring-temp-using-thermocouples.pdf)

---

[image]

[image]

Common mode LPF analysis

---

[image]

[image]

Differential mode LPF analysis

---

Added 1 nF

[image]

[image]

Differential mode LPF analysis with common mode filters

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: your second schematic makes no sense; you need to add the 10 kΩ in the lower "branch" as well.

Comment: Ups ı didnt notice that let me correct.

Comment: now you only need to add the two 1 nF as well!

Comment: It became 756 Hz. Is it my mistake that I connected GND to the negative section of Vac?

Comment: Your last simulation is still missing a point: lower V1 is tight to GND, not via 1 MOhm to GND. So you have a short circuit over R2 and C3! Perhaps if you do like in the schematics, the frequency will be 1.3 kHz? I mean add R3 and R6 to your simulation. then it will be right - I assume.

Comment: I built exactly the same circuit but the result is still the same.

Comment: It's a typo. If somebody made a formal answer of that, would you believe them i.e. is this an answerable question in reality?

Comment: Just confirming if I'm wrong. So my simulation inputs could also be wrong.

Comment: I just saw that [some people use -3dB and others -6dB](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84861) as point for cut off - so the author of the circuit mixed these two values? Or the author just measured it once - having C1 at upper tolerance with +80% perhaps? Or perhaps thinking falsely to cut C1 to half for the calculation. Anyway, with the output low pass of 100k and 1uF = 1.6Hz at -3dB, *the fC does not matter really* (and the [datasheet of AD8495](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8494_8495_8496_8497.pdf) only states typical values for freq. of ca. 30 kHz).

Comment: @BitLauncher really nice info!  The Result
However, in this case, it seems that they calculated the common mode filter for -3db and the differential filter for -6db.